# Data Transmission and Reconcilation

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I currently have a two way communication with a third party and we exchange data very frequently. There is an automatic process which processes any changes of data into a database. The problem is CSV used to transmit the data doesn't always have exactly identical

Data sent:

```
╔═══════════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Unique Identifier ║ Client Name ║ Fund ID ║  Capital  ║ Investment Date ║ Mtd. Return ║ Acct. Number ║
╠═══════════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ AB10001           ║ John Smith  ║     123 ║ 40,000.00 ║ 9/1/15          ║ 0.95        ║       123456 ║
║ AB10002           ║ John Smith  ║     221 ║ 50,000.00 ║ 9/1/15          ║ 0.23        ║       123456 ║
╚═══════════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Data Received:

```
╔═══════════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║  Client Name  ║ Fund ID ║  Capital  ║ Investment Date ║ Mtd. Return ║ Acct. Number ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ John A. Smith ║     123 ║ 40,000.00 ║ 9/1/15          ║ 0.84        ║       123456 ║
║ John A. Smith ║     221 ║ 50,000.00 ║ 9/1/15          ║ 0.25        ║       123456 ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

I send out a unique identifier, however the third party doesn't map this piece of data. Therefore, it is never received in return. I have to identify a way to correlate this data based off the other columns. Keeping in mind that this data is for 100+ entries during every transmission, account numbers, investment dates, capitals, and fund ID's are not unique. However, narrowing the scope down to every client, makes it easier to identify what specific transaction it is. The problem is that the data received (particularly the name) isn't always 1-to-1. As in the example above, John Smith was sent out, and I received John A. Smith.

Is there any way to create an object, and compare all of the fields that do not change (Investment Date, Capital, Fund ID, Client Name, Account Number) and create a comparator threshhold. ie. if the data is 95% matching, we can process it, otherwise reject it for manual reconciliation.

Comment: Anything is possible. If you are asking how to go about it, I'm afraid you really need to ask a more detailed question for us to hlep you

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have some wider context regarding your relationship with this third party, and the nature of the data being passed back & forth.  It seems extraordinary to me that they do not furnish you with any means of tracing records through their system!

Comment: To give a perspective, the third party doesn't store the unique ID that we create upon the creation of a transaction. Therefore, we send them information with our unique ID, and they return it without it. Also, a we can have different ID's for the same fund, i.e. they store S&P 500 as fund id 200, but we have it as 210.